# Can I base a calculation on multiple drop-down options?

Tags: cognito-forms

I have a drop down menu with several options. Is there a way I can put a calculation based on each option? I mean, for example, lets say for a certain item chosen on drop down menu it show "3%". Then client adds on the currency field "$100". 
I would like to put a calculation that would should the client the total result = "$3"

Answer (score 1):

[Calculations](http://help.cognitoforms.com/calculations-overview) in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) can reference all fields and perform just about any calculation you can think of.

In this example, if you have a `Choice` field called `Discount` and a `Currency` field called `Amount`, you would enter the following calculation for the discount amount:

`=(if Discount = "3%" then 0.03 else 0) * Amount`